# Rails Paperclip Carrierwave.. Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, carrierwave

Hey I'm doing something strange. Using both Paperclip & Carrierwave to determine which i like better because I am new to rails but here is the issue.

When I create a post using Paperclip, the image gets routed to the directory but does not display/render in any view.

When I create a post using Carrierwave, the image never gets routed or renders and I get an error withing the postscontroller saying.

```
 (undefined method `image_will_change!' for #Post:0x007fd039c02888)
 app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

I also get an error across the app when trying to edit any of the post that error is.

```
(undefined method 'image_changed?' for #Post:0x007fd03fc76fe8)
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:43:in `update'
```

---

Heres my code:

### (post.rb)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :image  
has_attached_file :content, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

### (postscontroller.rb)

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :destroy_all]


def index
@posts = Post.all
end


def show
end


def new
@post = Post.new
end


def edit
end

def create
@post = Post.new(post_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @post.update(post_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


def destroy
@post.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content, :no_image }
end
end



def destroy_all
@post.destroy_all
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to posts, notice: 'All Posts have bee successfully destroyed.'}
  format.json { head :no_content, :no_image}
end
end

def demo
@post = Post.all
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :content, :image)
end
end
```

### (imageuploader.rb)

```
  class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  storage :file
  def store_dir
  "images"
  end
```

### (add_content_to_posts.rb)

```
  class AddContentToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
  add_attachment :posts, :content
  end

  def self.down
  remove_attachment :posts, :content
  end
  end
```

### (add_image_to_posts.rb)

```
  class AddImageToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  add_column :posts, :images, :string
  end
  end
```

### (Schema.rb)

```
  create_table "posts", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "content_file_name"
    t.string   "content_content_type"
    t.integer  "content_file_size"
    t.datetime "content_updated_at"
    t.string   "images"
   end
```

Comment: Please add pointers in your code where your errors occur.

Comment: can you check what database columns do you have in posts table? when I saw `image_will_change` it may related image column is not there.

Comment: I fixed it.... I just started from scratched. 

I deleted the post scaffolding.
Deleted both AddImageToPost & AddContentToPost migrations
Then uninstalled both gems.
Then Reinstalled both gems.
Created the Scaffolding for the Post.
Followed by the creation of AddImageToPost & AddContentToPost migrations.

Rake db:migrate
Restarted the server and everything is now peaches...